# Nullable datetime to datetime converter automapper

Tags: datetime, automapper, nullable

I have a situation where my DTOs require `DateTime` properties but my POCOs use nullable datetimes. To avoid having to create `ForMember` mappings for every property with this condition I created an `ITypeConverter<DateTime?, DateTime>`. The problem I ran into is when both DTO and POCO have nullable DateTimes this converter is called. The `DestinationType` is `DateTime` even though the property is a nullable datetime.  Any idea how I would make this converter run only for actual nullable datetimes?

```cs
public class FooDTO
{
    public DateTime? FooDate { get; set; }
}

public class FooPoco
{
    public DateTime? FooDate { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<FooDTO, FooPoco>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime>()
              .ConvertUsing<NullableDateTimeConverter>();
        var poco = new FooPoco();
        Mapper.Map(new FooDTO() { FooDate = null }, poco);

        if (poco.FooDate.HasValue)
            Console.WriteLine(
                "This should be null : {0}",
                poco.FooDate.Value.ToString()); //Value is always set 
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Mapping worked");
    }
}

public class NullableDateTimeConverter : ITypeConverter<DateTime?, DateTime>
{
    // Since both are nullable date times and this handles converting
    // nullable to datetime I would not expect this to be called. 
    public DateTime Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var sourceDate = context.SourceValue as DateTime?;
        if (sourceDate.HasValue)
            return sourceDate.Value;
        else
            return default(DateTime);
    }
}
```

I found this post [AutoMapper TypeConverter mapping nullable type to not-nullable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806771/automapper-typeconverter-mapping-nullable-type-to-not-nullable-type) but it was little help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without looking I suspect its calling your `TypeCoverter` because its the best match for the types being converted.

If you create another `TypeConverter` with the correct types it should work fine. Eg:

```cs
public class DateTimeConverter : ITypeConverter<DateTime?, DateTime>
{
    public DateTime Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var sourceDate = context.SourceValue as DateTime?;
        if (sourceDate.HasValue)
            return sourceDate.Value;
        else
            return default(DateTime);
    }
}

public class NullableDateTimeConverter : ITypeConverter<DateTime?, DateTime?>
{
    public DateTime? Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var sourceDate = context.SourceValue as DateTime?;
        if (sourceDate.HasValue)
            return sourceDate.Value;
        else
            return default(DateTime?);
    }
}
```

Note that if you wish these can be further simplified to

```cs
public class DateTimeConverter : TypeConverter<DateTime?, DateTime>
{
    protected override DateTime ConvertCore(DateTime? source)
    {
        if (source.HasValue)
            return source.Value;
        else
            return default(DateTime);
    }
}

public class NullableDateTimeConverter : TypeConverter<DateTime?, DateTime?>
{
    protected override DateTime? ConvertCore(DateTime? source)
    {
        return source;
    }
}
```

Then just initialise both converters:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime>().ConvertUsing<DateTimeConverter>();
Mapper.CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime?>().ConvertUsing<NullableDateTimeConverter>();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Comment: You should be able to simplify it a bit further if you wanted and inline `NullableDateTimeConverter` into `CreateMap`. There wasn't much to gain so I didn't bother, but might make it look a little less *hokie* :)

Comment: Can you share a sample lines of codes to do this inline.