# AutoMapper won't map Int32 to Int64 at runtime

Tags: .net, vb.net, unit-testing, windows-services, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper in a windows service and I test every line of code.

Having this DTO:

```
Public Class Werkgever
    'left out other properties for readability
    Public Property Rsz As Int64
End Class
```

and the following Entity (generated by EF)

```
Partial Public Class GetWerkgeverByID_Result
    'left out other properties for readability
    Public Property WgRSZ As Integer
End Class
```

With the following Map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap(Of GetWerkgeverByID_Result, Werkgever)() _
.ForMember(Function(target) target.Rsz,
           Sub(options) options.MapFrom(Function(source) source.WgRSZ)) _
.IgnoreAllNonExisting()
```

For the following controller method:

```
 Public Async Function ExecuteFilter(request As IGetWerkgeverRequestV1) As Task(Of Werkgever) Implements ICanExecuteFilter(Of IGetWerkgeverRequestV1, Task(Of Werkgever)).ExecuteFilter
    Dim result = Await _repo.GetWerkgeverById(request.Id.Value)
    Return Mapper.Map(Of Werkgever)(result)
 End Function
```

The following test **succeeds**:

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Overrides Sub ExecuteFilter_should_return_a_werkgever()
    AutomapperBootstrapper.CreateMaps()
    Dim result As Werkgever
    Const testRsz As Integer = 67193160
    'AutoMapper should cover the conversion
    Dim expectedRsz As Int64 = CType(testRsz, Int64)
    Dim fakeResult = New GetWerkgeverByID_Result() _
             With {.WgRSZ = testRsz}
    FakeRepo.GetWerkgeverByIdInt32 = Function(id) Task.Run(Function() fakeResult)
    'Act
    result = _sut.ExecuteFilter(DefaultRequest).Result
    'Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedRsz, result.Rsz)
End Sub
```

However at runtime when I try to get the same thing as the test mocks (same value for ID) I get the following exception:

> Message: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: Int32 -> Int64 System.Int32 -> System.Int64
>
> Destination path: Werkgever.Rsz.Rsz
>
> Source value: 67193160

**QUESTION:** Does anyone have any idea what I am missing? Maybe my test is poorly written? Maybe something specific for deployed windows services? I can work around it by making the DTO's property an Integer or excplicitly casting in the mapping .. but that doens't really solve the problem (being that the test succeeds and it fails at runtime)

Comment: In your test you convert the Int32 to an Int64 before asserting if they are equal. Does the runtime code do the same as the test code?

Comment: That's kind of the whole point of AutoMapper ;-) to convert it to an Int64

Comment: I guess I'm asking: if the mapping exists to do the conversion, why do you need to specify ANY conversion code? The error message suggests that the map isn't applied to cover what you're executing, or that the conversion doesn't happen in your Mapper.CreateMap(). EDIT: Should the map make use of .NotNullableLong ?

Comment: Whut? :p The test succeeds and I expect that AutoMapper filled the property of result.Rsz (which is an int64) with the value of the original int32.

I need this conversion code, because that's what AutoMapper is supposed to do (and does in the test, but not at runtime). Anyway I updated the question so that this is hopefully a bit more obvious.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806771/automapper-typeconverter-mapping-nullable-type-to-not-nullable-type or this website article: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/05/06/automapper-feature-custom-type-converters/

Comment: Well this is odd. AutoMapper even supports cast operators, but there might not be an implicit cast operator here. I suspect that it's because the cast operator is explicit. Those types do support IConvertible, which isn't supported OOTB